# I can't access a global array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, scope, global-variables, declaration

Hello first thing first forgives me  if I have mistakes in my English, I am beginner in c++ and I need help with this problem please

```
//global variables
int RangeOfArray; 
int arr[RangeOfArray-1]; // error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token


void functionOne(){} // I need to access the array here.

void functionTwo(){} // as well here.


int main (){

 cout<<"Type the length number of the array  :  ";
 cin >> RangeOfArray;`

}
```

As you can see I need the array (arr) everywhere in my program but I can't why? I don't know

Comment: An array has its space requirements determined at compile time, except for variable length arrays which will not be discussed here. Whatever value you have between `[` and `]` needs to be known when you compile. If you want a container with a dynamic size (determined at RUN time), use `std::vector`. Let us know if this is for a class project where you're not allowed to use `std::vector` so we can yell at clouds.

Comment: If this is for a class, please talk to your teaching staff and find out if you're allowed to pass variables to your functions. Using global variables is frowned upon, and should be avoided except in the most edgy of cases. If you think you want a global variable, you usually don't.

Comment: array sizes must be constants. Even if not, you are asking for a -1 sized array. Thats not going to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these declarations

```
//global variables
int RangeOfArray; 
int arr[RangeOfArray-1]; // error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token
```

there is declared the global variable `RangeOfArray` that is implicitly initialized by zero and then there is declared the variable length array `arr` with the size `-1` that is implicitly converted to the maximum value of the type `size_t` due to the usual arithmetic conversions because in C++ an expression that specifies a size of an array in its declaration is converted to the type `size_t`.

For starters variable length arrays is not a standard C++ feature. And moreover you may not declare a variable length array with static storage duration.

And secondly using the expression `-1` as the size of an array does not make a sense.

If you need a global variable that simulates an array then use the standard container `std::vector<int>`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//global variables
std::vector<int> arr;


void functionOne(){ /* ... */ } // I need to access the array here.

void functionTwo(){ /* ... */ } // as well here.


int main()
{
    size_t RangeOfArray;

    std::cout<<"Type the length number of the array  :  ";
    std::cin >> RangeOfArray;`

    arr.resize( RangeOfArray );
    //...
}
```

The vector provides member function `size` that reports the current number of elements stored in the vector. So you need not to make the variable `RangeOfArray` global.

Pay attention to that it is not a good idea to use global variables.

So you could declare the vector in main and pass it by reference to functions where it is required.

Comment: Thank you very much, I loved your detailed explanation of the solution to the problem

Answer (score 1):

An array needs a size that can be known at compile time. `RangeOfArray` is not known at compile time. Also, you are declaring the array and then trying to assign a size to it, which is not possible. You'll need dynamic arrays for this purpose:

```
#include <iostream>

int RangeOfArray;
int* arr;

int main() {

    std::cout << "Type the length number of the array  :  ";
    std::cin >> RangeOfArray;

    arr = new int[RangeOfArray];
}
```

..or preferably, `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::cout << "Type the length number of the array  :  ";
    int vec_size; std::cin >> vec_size;

    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.resize(vec_size);
}
```

Any of the 2 options work.

Answer (score 0):

> why [I cannot use the array]?

The error message that you quoted explains why:

> > error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token

The size of an array must be compile time constant. `RangeOfArray-1` is not compile time constant. Hence it cannot be used as the size of an array.

If you want to create an array whose size is determined at runtime, you must use dynamic storage. Simplest solution is to use `std::vector` from the standard library.

---

Another issue is that you try to use the variable before it has been assigned a value (although it has been zero-initialised). That approach doesn't work in imperative programming languages such as C++. You must assign a value before you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

##### Mistake 1

In standard C++, the size of an array must be a **compile time constant**. So when you wrote:

```
int RangeOfArray; 
int arr[RangeOfArray-1]; //not standard c++
```

The statement `int arr[RangeOfArray-1];` is not standard C++ since `RangeOfArray - 1` is not a *constant expression*.

##### Mistake 2

From [Array declarators documentation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf):

> If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value **greater than zero**.

This means even if `RangeOfArray` was a constant expression, due to [static initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization), `RangeOfArray` will be initialized with `0` and so the expression `RangeOfArray - 1` evaluates to the negative integer `-1`. And according to the above quoted statement, `int[-1];` isn't valid.

##### Solution

Better would be to use `std::vector` as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
//global variables
 
std::vector<int> arr; // empty vector


void functionOne(){
    std::cout<<"functionOne called with: "<<arr.size()<<std::endl;
} 

void functionTwo(){
    std::cout<<"functionTwo called with: "<<arr.size()<<std::endl;
} 


int main (){
 int RangeOfArray = 0;
 std::cout<<"Type the length number of the array  :  ";
 std::cin >> RangeOfArray;
 
 //resize the vector named arr 
 arr.resize(RangeOfArray);
 
 //call functionOne 
 functionOne();
 
 //call functionTwo
 functionTwo();

}
```